# mysql how to assign a date value to a variable

Tags: mysql, date, triggers

I'm creating a trigger (before insert) in order to add an updated date, starting from an existing date stored in another table.
Seems that my variable dtStart gets the null value.
This is the code:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE dtStart DATE;
    DECLARE dtRenew DATE;
    DECLARE numD INT;


    SET dtStart = (SELECT dtStart FROM tblCourses WHERE idCourse = NEW.idCourse); 
    SET numD = (SELECT setting FROM tblSettings WHERE codSetting = 'D_EXPIRE_C'); 

    SET dtRenew = DATE_ADD(dtStart, INTERVAL numD DAY);
    SET NEW.dtExpiration = dtRenew;


END
```

Comment: RESOLVED
The problem was the variable name!
Instead of
 DECLARE dtStart DATE; 
it works using
 DECLARE dtStart_anothername DATE;

Comment: You don't need to rename the variable. If you prefix the column name in the subquery, it will work as expected.

Comment: Also, you should put an in answer to this question and then accept it as resolved. That way it's clear that this question is no longer an open issue.